# Asus N56JR keeps dropping the Wireless from time to time on Windows (8.1 and 10)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wifi-driver

I have an Asus N56JR which is a nice device except for the Wireless. Since the beginning it loses the connection to my router from time to time. Since I have another mobile device with Wireless activated I can tell for sure that the router is not the problem since the other device is working during the time when the notebook does not.

Resetting the Wireless by switching flight mode on and off again solves the issue every time. But this is only a workaround. I installed the latest driver.

What else can I do? Anyone solved this issue yet? Support tells me to reinstall. I do not want to do that.

Has anyone replaced the card by another card? Which one would be a good option?

[image: Eigenschaften von Intel Dual Band Wireless-N 7260]

My installed driver is shown above and the official site is here: http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=390&m=N56JR&os=&hashedid=NhyIh5IdAzzkKh7Y

Comment: What's the [hardware ID](http://bit.ly/1jbWdLD)? Intel provides a [newer, generic driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23868&lang=eng) (version `17.0.2.5`). Assuming your [operating system is 64-bit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218/en-us), you need to download the `Wireless_x.x.x_De164.zip` file. Extract the archive somewhere and [install the driver manually](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9695-driver-install-device-manager-windows-8-a.html). If you're still getting the same issues even with the updated driver, try booting any Linux live distro.

Comment: The hardware ID is: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08B1&SUBSYS_40608086&REV_73
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08B1&SUBSYS_40608086
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08B1&CC_028000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08B1&CC_0280
I managed to install the newer driver, it was not the Wireless_17.0.2_De164 but the Wireless_17.0.2_Win64 that did work. Now let's hope this one is better. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, 4 years later, the same problem persists. Autoupdate of the driver does not work, neither. I updated today to a new version by downloading and installing [the software](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27750/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-Windows-10?product=75439). But I will continue using the notebook because everything else just works fine and I like it anyway.

The solution was to deactivate the device and buying a [FRITZ!WLAN Stick AC 860](https://avm.de/produkte/fritzwlan/fritzwlan-stick-ac-860/). Now it works as intended.

[image: New driver]

Comment: Reverted to the older driver again, the new one is even worse.