# Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 keeps disconnecting

Tags: wifi-driver

I have a Dell Latitude E5440 running windows 7 pro 64 bit. It has the Intel dual band ac 7260 adapter which disconnects from Wi-Fi on its own and will not reconnect again until I restart the computer. Also, the Wi-Fi icon freezes after it disconnects, even if I click on it so as to connect it never responds. I have uninstalled and deleted the old drivers, reinstalled the latest but still the same problem. I also tried using drivers straight from intel's website but no difference. Please help if you know of any trick.

Comment: I edited your question, as questions asking for shopping advice is off topic here :)

Comment: I have the same problem on my notebook (see https://superuser.com/questions/752794/asus-n56jr-keeps-dropping-the-wireless-from-time-to-time-on-windows-8-1-and-10/1330409#1330409), seems as if the Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 is not a good option. Deactivating Bluetooth was suggested, I am trying this atm.

Comment: I suggest buying an external device, like the [FRITZ!WLAN Stick AC 860](https://avm.de/produkte/fritzwlan/fritzwlan-stick-ac-860/). Worked for me.